# Nested named routes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Lets say you have a two models with blog posts and comments set up like this:

```
class post 
has_many :comments
```

and the routing was set up pretty much the same way:

```
map.resources :posts, :has_many => :comments
```

When I go to make a new comment it shows up as localhost::3000/postname/comments/new

What should you do in order to make the url read something like: localhost::3000/postname/shoutout   ?

The reason I want to do this is because this particular page will have more than just a new comment form on it.

I have no trouble naming routes but I'm having trouble figuring out what to do with a nested one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routes have nothing to do with the forms that are on the page, I'm not sure what the problem is?

If you want to have `/postname/shoutout` go to to CommentsController#new you'll need to map the route manually:

```
map.connect '/:post_id/shoutout', :controller => 'comments', :action => 'new'
```

Comment: Not really a big problem, just wanted something other than /postname/comment/new. How would this link be represented in the view by the way?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it really. Just didn't want long trailing urls.

Comment: Well /comments is shorter than /shoutouts =)  Either way, I'd try not to spend too much time on URIs unless it's to improve your SEO as 99% of users don't even notice them.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably leave it alone unless someone says something.

Comment: in future, if you wanted you can always do, this `map.resources :as => 'shoutouts'`, this will make the route appear as `/shoutouts/new` instead of `/comments/new`.

Answer (score 3):

```
map.resources :posts, :has_many => :comments, :collection => {:shoutout => :get}
```

Key feature is `:collection`, which points of pairs: 'name' => 'method', and you need to implement this name in controller (and views)

Comment: To me, this is the most 'hygienic' approach.